# Float wrong calculation

Tags: c#

The result must be 806603.77 but why I get 806603.8 ?

```
float a = 855000.00f;
float b = 48396.23f;

float res = a - b;
Console.WriteLine(res);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: if you want exact result you shoul use Decimal

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Float and Double are prone to rounding issues. Use `Decimal` as @Sergio recommended. You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: Not only is the result not what you want, `b` will not even contain an exact representation of the number you initialised it with.

Comment: In this case, `double` would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead because [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has `32-bit` with ***7 digit*** precision only that is why the result differs, on other hand `decimal` has `128-bit` with ***28-29 digit*** precision.

```
decimal a = 855000.00M;
decimal b = 48396.23M;

decimal res = a - b;
Console.WriteLine(res);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output: `806603.77`

Answer (score 3):

A `float` (also called `System.Single`) has a precision equivalent to approximately **seven** decimal figures. Your `res` difference needs **eight** significant decimal digits. Therefore it is to be expected that there is not enough precision in a `float`.

ADDITION:

Some extra information: Near 806,000 (806 thousand), a `float` only has four bits left for the fractional part. So for `res` it will have to choose between

```
806603 + 12/16 == 806603.75000000, and
806603 + 13/16 == 806603.81250000
```

It chooses the first one since it's closest to the ideal result. But both of these values are output as `"806603.8"` when calling `ToString()` (which `Console.WriteLine(float)` does call). A maximum of 7 significant decimal figures are shown with the general `ToString` call. To reveal that two floating-point numbers are distinct even though they print the same with the standard formatting, use the format string `"R"`, for example

```
Console.WriteLine(res.ToString("R"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `float` has limited precision (32 bits). Use `double` or `decimal` if you want more precision.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that just blindly using Decimal isn't good enough.

Read the link posted by Oded: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Only *then* decide on the appropriate numeric type to use.

Don't fall into the trap of thinking that just using Decimal will give you exact results; it won't always.

Consider the following code:

```
Decimal d1 = 1;
Decimal d2 = 101;
Decimal d3 = d1/d2;
Decimal d4 = d3*d2; // d4 = (d1/d2) * d2 = d1

if (d4 == d1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yay!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Urk!");
}
```

If Decimal calculations were exact, that code should print "Yay!" because d1 should be the same as d4, right?

Well, it doesn't.

Also be aware that Decimal calculations are thousands of times slower than double calculations. They are not always suitable for non-currency calculations (e.g. calculating pixel offsets or physical things such as velocities, or anything involving transcendental numbers and so on).

Comment: Another funny fact to note is that since `decimal.MaxValue` is `79228...`, there is a higher precision for numbers whose significant digits start by something lower than this, than there is for number whose significant digits are higher. To see what I mean, consider `800m / 3m * 3m` versus `500m / 3m * 3m`. First note that neither 800 nor 500 is evenly dicisible by 3, so the quotient will have an infinite tail of `666...` which a `System.Decimal` will have to terminate with `...667` at some point. Still, because 800 is over the `79228...` limit, and 500 is under it, the precision differs.

Comment: I'm talking about the threshold `79228...` where precision changes from 29 to 28 significant digits.